# Aws Glue Crawler Recrawl Policy in CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I want to set the [Recrawl Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-crawling.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-crawling-RecrawlPolicy) while creating Glue Crawler through CloudFormation Stack.

Not able find way to set Recrawl policy through CloudFormation.

Please help on adding this configuration in this templateother wise let me know if it can't be done.

```
Parameters:                                                                                                       
  CFNCrawlerName:  
    Type: String
    Default: cfn-crawler-flights-1
  CFNDatabaseName:
    Type: String
    Default: cfn-database-flights-1
  CFNTablePrefixName:
    Type: String
    Default: cfn_sample_1_  

Resources:
  CFNRoleFlights:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "glue.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "root"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action: "*"
                Resource: "*"

  CFNDatabaseFlights:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Database
    Properties:
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      DatabaseInput:
        Name: !Ref CFNDatabaseName
        Description: "AWS Glue container to hold metadata tables for the flights crawler"
  CFNCrawlerFlights:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref CFNCrawlerName
      Role: !GetAtt CFNRoleFlights.Arn
      Description: AWS Glue crawler to crawl flights data
      DatabaseName: !Ref CFNDatabaseName
      Targets:
        S3Targets:
          - Path: "s3://crawler-public-us-east-1/flight/2016/csv"
      TablePrefix: !Ref CFNTablePrefixName
      SchemaChangePolicy:
        UpdateBehavior: "UPDATE_IN_DATABASE"
        DeleteBehavior: "LOG"
      Configuration: "{\"Version\":1.0,\"CrawlerOutput\":{\"Partitions\":{\"AddOrUpdateBehavior\":\"InheritFromTable\"},\"Tables\":{\"AddOrUpdateBehavior\":\"MergeNewColumns\"}}}"
```

I found this Cloud formation template on [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/populate-with-cloudformation-templates.html#sample-cfn-template-crawler-s3)

Comment: Does not seem to be possible in Cloud Formation just yet. I think the recrawl policy is a new feature and was not yet added to CF. That's the CF [Crawler reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-crawler.html)

Comment: Any other way around to do this ?

Comment: A good alternative to Cloud Formation is the terraform (an opensource infrastructure as code sotfware) - but even they did not add this option yet (see [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16013)). 

If you want to programatically create it, use boto3 or aws cli - they already support it. Otherwise, be patient - Cloud Formation is usually updated with new features with a delay.

Comment: Still not implemented, if anyone is checking this in May 2021